# How to select the right 20vdc motor to match 18v/1.5ah-5ah range batteries without burning it out

Tags: dc-motor, amperage, battery-operated

I would like to know how to select brushed dc motor that can comfortably run on 18v/3ah-4ah & 5ah Lith.ion batteries without burning out with the higher Ah capacities.

"What am I missing technically here"

I have had a 20v dc motor nearly burn out using the 18v/3ah, but then runs fine with 18v/1.5ah batteries.

(For the Project I need 18v brushed motor capable of around 2000rpm-4000rpm/no load, with an output wattage between 300w-600w, typical shape/cylindrical, dimensions of around 40-50mm diameter and 60-80mm length).

How would I select the right current capacity of the motor "how do you do that" it obviously can't be the voltage capacity.

Could anyone kindly advise me on how to select the right motor for the project, powered by the above mentioned batteries, any advise would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please read the the [help] to learn how to ask good questions. Your current question reads like a 'shopping question' which is outside of the type of questions answered here, will not be answered, and will be closed.

Comment: I think the statement "I have had a 20v dc motor nearly burn out using the 18v/3ah, but then runs fine with 18v/1.5ah batteries." is unlikely. There is more information needed. You may have your understanding backwards. An unloaded motor will take the same current no matter what the battery, assuming the battery can provide enough current. So running at 18V, and having a battery which is capable of delivering more current *makes no difference*, the motor will not burn out. However, if the motor is stalled, extra current capacity might burn it out. Did that happen?

Comment: First pick your motor, to be powerful enough for your load. Then pick batteries, powerful enough for your motor or *any size bigger*. If the motor is right for the load, then big batteries will not burn out the motor.

Comment: Most likely, you had a bad/mislabeled motor to start out with. If the 18v/3ah burned it & the 18v/1.5ah didn't, it's most likely because the smaller battery sacrificed itself by lowering the voltage (across the smaller battery's higher internal resistance) to a voltage (well below 18v) the bad motor wouldn't burn itself up at. As @gbulmer said, the motor should self-regulate its own current (at design voltage and load) within a safe range; a motor burning out when supplied with design voltage *at any available current* is either defective, or being used outside of its design parameters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question demonstrates a "simply wrong" understanding of critical basics. A basic understanding of voltages, currents and impedance is necessary as a prerequisite for **any** *safe* Electrical Engineering.

Comment: I'm voting to close both because the question seems to show 'simply wrong' understanding, *and* because we have asked for more information to clarify the actual project, but the question has not been improved. Without more information, it looks like a shopping question.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, the bad motor was being used outside its parameters as Robherc KV5ROB said thats why I would Like to know how to select the right motor, I need the same motor in this tool: http://bit.do/18v-circularsaw-730watt-3100rpm, How can I find one like it, that is all I want to know.

Comment: I know it is off topic and a bad question, however I still need to know how to the select the right motor, I don't know who else to ask, only professionals like you guys. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As to your original question (why did it work with a smaller battery, but burn up with a larger?), you have not given nearly enough information. What was the load? What speed did the motor run with each battery? How long did the smaller battery last? How hot did the motor get with the small battery? If your run time was battery-limited, an obvious answer is that the smaller battery ran out of juice before the motor reached failure temperature, but if you had run it twice as long you'd have smoked that motor, too. But there is no way to know. You just haven't told us enough about what happened.

You have much bigger problems, though, and they start here

> (For the Project I need 18v brushed motor capable of around
>   2000rpm-4000rpm/no load, with an output wattage between 300w-600w,
>   typical shape/cylindrical, dimensions of around 40-50mm diameter and
>   60-80mm length).

Let's think about this. 300 to 600 watts is about 1/2 to 3/4 horsepower. Your motor size is about 2 inches in diameter by 3 inches long. That is a very high power density.

Look [here, for instance](http://www.portescap.com/motor-solutions/motor-power-density) at a line of DC brush motors which tout high power density. At a diameter of 24 mm, maximum power is about 9 watts. Doubling all dimensions brings it up to 48 mm dia with a nominal power capacity of about 72 watts. In other words, you're asking for about 10 times the power density you can reasonably expect to get.

Another way to look at this is to look at power and current. 600 watts at 20 volts is 30 amps. 30 amps is a very high current for a motor this size.

Finally, specifying your no-load speed is useless, unless you plan to run the motor with no load. And the fact that you apparently don't know your load requirements suggests that your 300 to 600 watt power requirement is completely bogus. You need to determine the load characteristics (both speed and torque),  and from there you can determine your power requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the the answers, You guys make me look, I Definitely got the wattage wrong I was only going off this: http://bit.do/18v-circularsaw-730watt-3100rpm, These are the motors I need and I don't know still dont know how to select a motor the same or close the circular saw in the link, the batteries used are Makita Brand 1.5-3-4&5Ah.

Comment: I may need to get an engineer to help me, Nm/torque/load/rpm/current/volts. I still need to know how to select a motor like the one in the circular saw link. Once again thank you everyone for setting me straight I will take the question down soon, if no one can help me select the right motor I need for the job. Cheers

Comment: @BuildaBob - Would you please pay attention? "I still need to know how to select a motor", "I will take the question down soon, if no one can help me select the right motor I need for the job." So why won't you tell us what you need? What RPM? What torque? You say "These are the motors I need" but you don't say why? Do you like their color? Do you have one on hand? Stop playing coy and hiding your requirements. Tell us exactly what you want to do, and maybe then we can help you. If you won't do that, you're wasting all our time - and yours.